# Iverson bracket identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation

While trying to prove the following [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) identity I've already filled a few pages with failed attempts

$$ [1\leq j < k+j \leq n] = [1\leq k \leq n] [1\leq j \leq n-k]  $$

(with $j,k,n \in \mathbb{N}$)

I've encountered this while reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025). This identity is implied by the following transition (between pages 40 and 41):

$$ \sum_{1\leq j< k+j \leq n} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{1\leq k \leq n} \sum_{1\leq j \leq n-k} \frac{1}{k} $$

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Draw a diagram in the $(j,k)$-plane with dots representing all points satisfying the constraints, perhaps starting form small $n$, and work it out form there.

Comment: I will try that too. I was under the impression that an algebraic proof would be available using identities previously discussed in the chapter but I might be wrong.

Comment: Someone showed me the following drawing https://i.imgur.com/so9p0AR.png which I think is a verification for n=5. It does suggest that the antidiagonal is involved, which is nice, but more would be needed to complete the proof. Also the argument depends on the graphical representation which is no longer available with >=4 indices. Actually this is why I was looking for an algebraic proof. It would be even nicer if there was a mechanized way to generate all relevant factorizations of Iverson brackets (but that's probably too much for now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integers $j, k$ is
$$
\begin{align}
& [1\leq j < k+j \leq n] = 1 \\
\iff & 1 \le j < k+j \le n \\
\iff & j \ge 1 \text{ and } k \ge 1 \text{ and } k+j \le n \\
\iff & 1 \le k \le n \text{ and } 1 \le j \le n-k \\
\iff &  [1\leq k \leq n] \cdot [1\leq j \leq n-k] = 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see, so in step 3, you realized j<k+j is superfluous so you dropped it. And then you factorized into a range for k and one for j. That makes sense. I'm upvoting your answer.

Comment: @wsdookadr: I transformed the middle inequality $j < k+j$ from the second line to $k \ge 1$. Of course, if $j, k$ are assumed to be *positive* integers then all the $j \ge 1$ and $k \ge 1$ are superfluous.